# IIS Application Pool reverted to v2.0 .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, iis

Ok, so I'm not really sure where to put this.

I support a plant that runs a webpage to make changes to the process.

It runs on .net framework 4.0

For some reason (they claim they have done nothing) it reverted everything in IIS to v2.0 (this has happened twice)

What could possibly do this / how could I find out what did this...

Comment: Have you run "aspnet_regiis -i" command? If yes, try to run using -iru parameters.

Comment: yes that is how I fixed the issue, but I don't know why the issue happend

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command using only -i parameter and you have both framework (2 and 4) applications on the server, it will reset all to framework 2.0. Use -iru will solve the problem.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: but lets say 2.0 and 4.0 are both on the machine, what could switch everything from 4.0 to 2.0 all of a sudden.